# Where nginx stores client's IP address?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

It write a log here:
/var/log/nginx/access.log, with a content:
**ip**/login/time/browser_type/

Answer (score 0):

nginx carries a directive which specifies where you want to store the logs, Have a look at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html.
Usually it is var/log/nginx/access.log
Hope this helps!